# Help with Object Design for Asynchronous Population of UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, concurrency

Greetings collective,

I am new to Cocoa and have been tasked with working on a prototype application for iPhone and iPad running 4.2. I am having trouble designing a process that will backfill data into a custom object that I am using to populate a UIScrollView. Each custom object displays movie data (artwork, cast, etc.) and this data is called from a REST service.

I would like this Movie object to be responsible for it's rendering and therefore "farm out" it's data needs to a separate object that can do the actual REST calls, JSON parsing etc. I've been trying to wrap my head around using delegates, or NSOperation's or direct callbacks to deliver a solution, but I'm having trouble discerning which avenue to pursue.

I know I need to process this data in the background, to keep the UI alive on the main thread, but I struggle with how to engineer the connections between these objects:

```
TheaterViewController //ViewController that contains the UIScrollView
```

Currently, I am populating TheaterViewController's UIScrollView with 11 (arbitrary allotment) MovieView items - MovieView shows an ActivityIndicator to let the user know it's working on delivering the content

```
MovieItem  //a single movie and it's respective data

MovieView  //individual View that displays a single MovieItem content

DataAgent  //background-capable object that fetches data from app server

DataWarehouse //Singleton-designed class that maintains an NSMutableArray of MovieItem's
```

In my current design, TheaterViewController populates the UIScrollView with 11 MovieView's. Each MovieView then goes about getting it's own data. I know how to get DataAgent to check DataWarehouse for it's content and if not present, then call the REST service. What I don't know how to do, is inform/callback/post to MovieView that DataAgent has finished getting the data (preferably in an asynchronous fashion) so it can render it's completed view.

Can anyone point me to a document, or example that does this kind of asynchronous callback process?

Thanks in advance for any pointers you good folks come up with -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegation would definitely be a good route to follow. I would make a `DataAgentDelegate` protocol which contains an `@required` method called something like `-(void)dataFetchComplete`. It would all be implemented as follows:

In DataAgent.h

```
@interface DataAgent : NSObject {
    id<DataAgentDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<DataAgentDelegate> delegate;
```

In DataAgent.m

```
- (void) fetchingComplete {
    if (delegate != nil) {
        [delegate dataFetchComplete];
    }
}
```

In MovieView.h

```
@interface MovieView : NSObject <DataAgentDelegate> {
    //...
}
```

In MovieView.m

```
- (void) startDataFetch {
    DataAgent *dataAgent = [[DataAgent alloc] init];
    dataAgent.delegate = self;
    [dataAgent startFetching];
}


- (void) dataFetchComplete {
    //render fetched assets in view 
}
```

I can't think of any specific example programs for this, but it's a very common thing to do. Delegation comes in really handy when you're dealing with asynchronous events. I hope this helps!

Comment: Arman - Thanks for your response. I'm going to plug this solution into my source and see how it shakes out. I am also taking a look at GCD-based solutions utilizing dispatch_get_global_queue().